# I need to compare Synapse notebooks in two different branches but all tabs are changing to the other branch

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-notebooks

I had opened two synapse notebooks . The first one was opened in `my-feature` branch.  The second was opened in `develop` branch.  I noticed that the first notebook got switched over to `develop` automatically. That was *not* my intent.

More specifically, the task is to compare the versions of a single notebook between the branches.  How can that be done [given synapse is switching all notebooks to same branch] ?